# How to parse a single field through Gson

Tags: java, android, gson

I have this JSON

```
[
  {"Description":"When settir\n"}
]
```

And my container class is

```
    class MessageContainer 
{

    private String Description;

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }

}
```

I get an exception when I use

```
MessageContainer container = mGson.fromJson(result, MessageContainer.class);
```

The exception reads EXPECTED BEGIN OBJECT , but found string .

Anyone knows what gives ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[
  {"Description":"When settir\n"}
]
```

This is used for array list

```
{"Description":"When settir\n"}
```

This is simple object

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MessageContainer m = new MessageContainer();
    m.setDescription("When settir\n");
    ArrayList<MessageContainer> list = new ArrayList<MessageContainer>();
    list.add(m);
    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(list));
    String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
    ArrayList<MessageContainer>  resultList = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<MessageContainer>>() {}.getType());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it's an Array of `MessageContainer` and not a single `MessageContainer` instance.

So your `fromJson` should be

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<MessageContainer>>(){}.getType();
List<MessageContainer> container = new Gson().fromJson(json, type);
```